# Missing parenthesis on Jquery function

Tags: jquery, function

Don't laugh, but i've been looking at this for like 20 minutes and can't figure out where i'm missing a closing parentheses.

```js
$("#search-field").keyup(function() {
  var keyword = $(this).attr("value");
  $("#search-field").load(
    $.post('endpoint/dummy.php', {
      search: keyword
    }, function(result) {
      var data = result;
      $.each(data, function(i, l) {
        $('#tags').append(
          '<span value="' + l + '" class="tag-word">' + l + '</span> '
        );
      });
    });
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Don't think, there is any missing parentheses. What error are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the call to `$("#search-field").load` - which expects a function.

```
$("#search-field").keyup(function(){
    var keyword =  $(this).attr("value");
    $("#search-field").load(
        $.post('endpoint/dummy.php', {search: keyword}, function(result){
            var data = result;
            $.each(data, function( i, l ){
                $('#tags').append(
                    '<span value="' + l + '" class="tag-word">' + l + '</span> '
                );
            });
        }); // <-- The semicolon is not expected because this is going as a parameter to `.load()`
    );
});
```

You can fix the problem by passing an anonymous function to `.load()`. Something like:

```
$("#search-field").keyup(function(){
    var keyword =  $(this).attr("value");
    $("#search-field").load(
        function() {
            $.post('endpoint/dummy.php', {search: keyword}, function(result){
                var data = result;
                $.each(data, function( i, l ){
                    $('#tags').append(
                        '<span value="' + l + '" class="tag-word">' + l + '</span> '
                    );
                });
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: maybe I am wrong but load expects an url and can perform `POST` and `GET` requests depending on the data provided as an `object` or `GET` if `data` provided as a `string` so you do not need to perform an extra `$.post` request inside the `$.load()` function

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I am referring this: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/